# Custom Login Page Sharepoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I was trying to Use a Custom Login Page instead of Default.aspx in sharepoint 2013, but when ever i'll use my page as custom sign in page, it doesn't redirect, it always says something went wrong with some Corelation ID and that's it , i have gone through LOGS also but i didn't get much clear info about this error.

Here i am attaching my .ASPX page FYR.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> 
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.LoginPage"   MasterPageFile="~/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/simple.master"       %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
&nbsp;
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="iCube Secure Pro Portal Sign In"  EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server"/>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<asp:login id="login" FailureText="<%$Resources:wss,login_pageFailureText%>" runat=server width="100%">
 <LayoutTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="FailureText" CssClass="ms-error" runat="server" />
     <p>
         <small>Server Time :</small>
         <input id="txtClock" type="text" size="18" name="Clock" readonly="readonly" style="border: none"><br />
         <input id="message" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="58" style="border: none; color: Red; font-size: x-small">
     </p>
     <table class="ms-input">
         <colgroup>
             <col style="width: 25%">
             <col style="width: 75%">
         </colgroup>
         <tr>
             <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                 <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="   <%$Resources:wss,login_pageUserName%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode' /></td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" AutoCompleteType="None" runat="server" CssClass="ms-long" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                 <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagePassword%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode' /></td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="password" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="None" runat="server" CssClass="ms-long" /></td>
         </tr>             
     </table>

     <!--<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height: 40px; width: 600px">
         <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="520" height="22">
             <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SLlogin.xap" />
             <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
             <param name="background" value="white" />
             <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
             <param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" />
             <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                 <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" />
             </a>
         </object>
         <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px"></iframe>
     </div>-->

    <table style="float: left" class="ms-input">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 28%">
            <col style="width: 72%">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td style="float: right">
                <asp:Button ID="login" CommandName="Login" Text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagetitle%>" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" Visible="false" Text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,login_pageRememberMe%>" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

 </LayoutTemplate>
 </asp:login>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
            appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
            return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + appSource + "\n";

        errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);
    }
</script>-->

<script runat="server" type="text/c#" >
    string ServerTime()
    {

        return System.DateTime.Now.ToString();//.ToLongTimeString();
    }    
</script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/*By George Chiang (JK's JavaScript tutorial)
http://javascriptkit.com
Credit must stay intact for use*/
var Digital = new Date("<%=ServerTime() %>")
    var day = Digital.getDate()
    var month = Digital.getMonth() + 1
    var year = Digital.getFullYear()
    var seconds = Digital.getSeconds()
    var hours = Digital.getHours()
    var minutes = Digital.getMinutes()
    var thours = hours
    var nDigital = new Date("<%=ServerTime() %>")
    var one_day = 1000 * 60
    var ClientDate = new Date()
    var diff = Math.ceil(nDigital.getTime() - ClientDate.getTime()) / (one_day)
    var stime = nDigital.getTime()
    var ctime = ClientDate.getTime()

    function show() {

        seconds = seconds + 1

        /*  if (minutes <= 9)
        minutes = "0" + minutes
        if (seconds <= 9)
        seconds = "0" + seconds*/
        if (seconds == 60) {
            minutes = minutes + 1
            seconds = 0
        }
        if (minutes == 60) {
            hours = hours + 1
            minutes = 0
            thours = hours
        }
        var dn = "AM"
        if (hours == 12) {
            dn = "PM"
        }
        if (hours > 12) {
            dn = "PM"
            thours = hours - 12
        }
        if (hours == 24) {
            dn = "AM"
        }
        if (thours == 12 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && dn == "AM") {
            window.location.reload(true)
        }
        if (hours == 0)
            thours = 12


        document.getElementById('txtClock').value = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + "  " + thours + ":" + minutes + ":"
+ seconds + " " + dn
        setTimeout("show()", 1000)
    }
    show()
    function display() {
        if ((-1 < diff) && (diff < 1))
            document.getElementById('message').value = ""
        else {
            document.getElementById('message').value = "Please set the system time to the server time displayed"
        }
    }
    display()      
</script>-->

<asp:hiddenfield ID="OTPhidden" runat="server"/>
```

and below is the error screen i get.

http://s10.postimg.org/ody43o409/Untitled.png

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was i was using

> asp:login id="login"

instead of this

> asp:login id="loginFormsUser" (Which is changed in sharepoint newer versions)

if somebody migrating their .aspx pages from Moss 2007 to sharepoint 2013 then this will play a tricky role, Hope this helps somoebody.